# How to make form that creates a new URL in a website?

Tags: php, html, forms

Example, on Craigslist users complete a form of what theyre looking for and once submitted it automatically creates a new URL hosted on the website URL. Sorry i don't know how to do this or what it is called. Anyone? How can i do this and what is it called? =) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mean like how StackOverflow has a URL for this question?

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662640/how-to-make-form-that-creates-a-new-url-in-a-website
```

All it takes is a simple .htaccess file, something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /questions/([0-9]+).*$ /question.php?id=$1
```

The whole "how-to-make..." thing is just the name of the question. I'm not entirely sure why many sites put that in the URL, possibly for SEO purposes, but it will automatically be filled in if you leave it out so I'm assuming it's optional.

Comment: im not sure how i can reach my .htaccess file. do u know how?

Comment: im not looking to make my url pretty, i'm trying to let the user create content on a seperate webpage on my url. and where can i create 1?

Answer (score 0):

This is done by a (mysql-)database, php and .htaccess resulting in dynamic url's.

A dynamic URL is a page address that results from the search of a database-driven web site or the URL of a web site that runs a script. In contrast to static URLs, in which the contents of the web page stay the same unless the changes are hard-coded into the HTML, dynamic URLs are generated from specific queries to a site's database. The dynamic page is basically only a template in which to display the results of the database query. Instead of changing information in the HTML code, the data is changed in the database.